# Immutable JS update all object in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have this map:

```
map1:{
    x: {...}
    y: {...}
    h: {...}
    j: {...}
    k: {...}
}
```

How can I update a common property, for example "selected" for all the objects in the map, and fastest as possible for react redux js with immutable js?

Thanks.

Comment: Try if `map` is fast enough for your purpose https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/map Like this `newMap = oldMap.map(value => value.set('selected', true))`

Comment: Hi. For 500 items it takes about 2 seconds. Is there faster way?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I get an error value.set is not a function

Comment: @user3712353 it's probably because value you are referring to is not a Immutable object but a normal javascript object.

Comment: I used groupBy on a List and received a Map of List. When I used @YuryTarabanko 's idea, it ran in negligible time on an initial array of 2600 items.

Answer (score 1):

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable');

let state = fromJS({
  map1: {
    x: { selected: false},
    y: { selected: false}
  }
});

console.log(state.update('map1', item => item.map( 
  keyValue => keyValue.set('selected', true)
)).toJS());

//result:{ map1: { x: { selected: true }, y: { selected: true } } }

//Have not tried other different methods to test speed, 
//since the field is not deep-nested, it should be fast enough, Hope this may help, :)
```